# Is there a way to test my HQL queries for my grails app?

Tags: hibernate, grails, intellij-idea

I've been trying to make it work for grails + intellij. So far I can already see the console by following the instructions on this [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-the-hibernate-console.html#open_console). But when I try to do a query, it will say something like `x is not mapped`.

```
hql> from users
[2017-03-08 20:49:34] users is not mapped [from users]
```

I just hate having to keep calling run-app whenever I made a few changes on my query only to find out it's wrong, there's a typo or whatever.

Comment: A unit test marked with `HibernateTestMixin` will initialize the real Hibernate environment so the test will have the full Hibernate capabilities available to it, including HQL execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grails console the command is:

```
grails console
```

Comment: The post is asking for a way to test HQL queries without having to go directly through his app. Can you do this via the Grails console?